# Do you know any open source Http client written in C that works on both on *nix and Windows?

Tags: c, httpclient

Do you know any open source Http client written in C that works on both on *nix and Windows? And can make the switch transparently?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Comment: It is, since I was looking for an Http Client library written in C that I can include in my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want Curl: http://curl.haxx.se/

Answer (score 0):

The [serf library](https://code.google.com/p/serf/) is an Apache-licensed, high-speed, multiplexed, pipelining HTTP(S) client. It is written in pure C, and is highly portable via the Apache Portable Runtime. The serf library is mature and used by [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), Apache OpenOffice, and Google's mod_pagespeed.